# Ruby: comparing dates of two Time objects

Tags: ruby, date, datetime, time

What is the best way to compare the dates of two Time objects in Ruby?

I have two objects such as:

```
time_1 = Time.new(2012,12,10,10,10)
time_2 = Time.new(2012,12,11,10,10)
```

In this example, the date comparison should return false.

Otherwise, same date, but different times, should return true:

```
time_1 = Time.new(2012,12,10,10,10)
time_2 = Time.new(2012,12,10,11,10)
```

I have tried to use `.to_date` that works for `DateTime` objects, but it is not supported by `Time`.

Comment: What problem with `<`, `>` or `==` in comparation of two Time objects? Just `if time_1 == time_2 ...`

Comment: `time_1 == time_2 #=> false`  `time_1 < time_2 #=> true`

Comment: I would like to compare only the dates. I will edit the question to make it clear.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just require the 'date' part of stdlib, then compare the dates:

```
require "date"
time1.to_date == time2.to_date
```

Job done.

Comment: Hi, I have a column in createdAt whose value is "2016-06-13T08:59:58+00:00" and I want to run a query find the object by createdAt and from the front end I aa sending "2016-06-13". How to find object by date excluding time? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

I have verified that this works for me:

```
time_1.strftime("%F") == time_2.strftime("%F")
```

The `%F` format returns the date portion only.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe just testing this way:

```
time_1.year == time_2.year && time_1.yday == time_2.yday
```

It'll be less resource consuming than string comparison.

monkey patch the class Time with this method and it i'll be nice to read

```
class Time
  def date_compare(time)
    year == time.year && yday == time_2.yday
  end
end

time_1.date_compare time_2
```

Answer (score 1):

to_date works just fine in ruby 2.0 and ruby 1.9.3 and ruby 1.9.2 http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.2/libdoc/date/rdoc/Time.html

```
>> time_1.to_date
=> #<Date: 2012-12-10 ((2456272j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
```

but it's not in the stdlib of ruby 1.8.7 http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.8.7/libdoc/time/rdoc/Time.html  - but then, your way of creating a time object doesn't work in that version either:

```
> time_1 = Time.new(2012,12,10,10,10)
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (5 for 0)
```

Comment: I get the following error:
`NoMethodError: undefined method `to_date' for 2012-12-10 10:10:00 +0100:Time`